# Where can I find the explanations about the part of cplex statistics that are obtained in output?

Tags: statistics, output, cplex

I would like to understand the meaning of the individual items of the statistic part that provides cplex in output. Also know if it is possible to save the solutions obtained in an excel file.
Thank you

Comment: There are very many different statistics and numbers available from CPLEX after a problem has been solved, and quite a few even when the pronlem is infeasible. This is not the place to describe what they all mean - look in the reference and/or user manuals for CPLEX to see what is available; but you will probably need to look up the meaning of many of them in one of the textbooks on optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can store statistics in variable:

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

int n1;
int n2;
int n3;

execute
{
  n1=cplex.getNcols();
  n2=cplex.getNrows();
  n3=cplex.getNNZs();
}
```

and then you can use SheetWrite to write those figures in an excel spreadsheet.

See [Excel, Rocket science and optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)